# In vscode prettier, how to use default settings if no config present in directory

Tags: prettier, prettier-vscode

If I set no value to `"prettier.configPath": ""` then it will use the default settings I set for the extension, but if I set it to `"prettier.configPath": "prettier.config.js"`, then it uses the config file.

How do I set it so it uses the default settings, but the config if present in directory?